# hiding tick value on the y axis that are negative

Tags: matplotlib, yaxis

I am trying to hide any value on the y axis that is less than 0.  I saw that to hide labels on the y axis I have to use something like this:

```
make_invisible = True
ax4.set_yticks(minor_ticks)

if (make_invisible):
    yticks=ax4.yaxis.get_major_ticks()      
    yticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
```

How can I tweak this so that if the ytick lable is negative it will be hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `set_xticks()` method to simply set those ticks that you want on the x axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
plt.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2],[4,6,2,7,1])

ticks = [tick for tick in plt.gca().get_xticks() if tick >=0]
plt.gca().set_xticks(ticks)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Replacing every `x` by a `y` will give you the according behaviour on the y axis.